# Auditing with spring-data-mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to enable auto audit fields with spring data mongodb as explained [here](http://www.javabydefault.com/2014/03/how-to-set-createdby-createddate.html). Below is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.abc.xyz.repository")
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017);
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential("user", "test", "abc123".toCharArray());
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress, Arrays.asList(mongoCredential));
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, "test");
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

But when I add @EnableMongoAuditing, I am getting the below error on starting the server.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoAuditingHandler': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6dca0c34' of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoAuditingRegistrar$MongoMappingContextLookup] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6dca0c34': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter] found for dependency [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter] found for dependency [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you check if you have `Spring Data MongoDB` dependency `1.9.4.RELEASE` or above as `mongoAuditingHandler` requires [MappingMongoConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.html) which is available in version `1.9.4.RELEASE` or above as per changelog - [spring-data-mongodb-changelog](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.9.6.RELEASE/changelog.txt), for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using 1.9.5.RELEASE. Can you please provide pointers on how to use MappingMongoConverter.

Comment: Found the issue. My configuration class wasn't extending AbstractMongoConfiguration.

Answer (score 20):

1 : Make sure you have `spring-data-mongodb`

2 :  if you are using `@CreatedDate` or `@LastModifiedDate` then you don't need any additional configuration.

```
class ClassName {

    .......

  @CreatedDate
  private DateTime createdDate;

  @LastModifiedDate
  private DateTime @lastModifiedDate;

}
```

3: if you are using `@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy` then you have to implement `AuditorAware<T>` SPI interface

```
class ClassName {

    .......

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

}

public class AppAuditor implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {

        // get your user name here
        return "xxxx";
    }

}
```

Implementation of AuditorAware based on Spring Security from spring doc

```
class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<User> {

  public User getCurrentAuditor() {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
      return null;
    }

    return ((MyUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUser();
  }
}
```